# Adding JPEG image to vector-based SVG

Tags: css, svg, vector, vector-graphics

Basically what I have is a SVG file which creates vertical lines of shadow at 45 degrees, this gives a nice effect on a webpage background with linear gradient at that same 45 degrees. However, I wish to add a picture to the SVG file so that inbetween two of the 6 lines created by the SVG there is a picture.

I first tried to just put it there ontop of the SVG using CSS but that didn't really work out, so then I tried looking up how to add non-vector images to a vector-based SVG but as this question probably shows is that I have little to no understanding of how SVG files work.

Below is the code of the current SVG file I'm using, I also added a picture to show how I would want it to look like.

Not sure if it matters, but I'm aware that the picture I want to add isn't a vector but as the picture I'll add is very, very large I'm pretty confident that most viewers of my webpage will see it smaller than it's original size, which should keep the quality a-ok.

If anyone would want to take a look at this and wants to help me find a solution for my problem, that'd be highly appreciated. Thank you!

[image: Example of what I want the end result to look like]

```css
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1000px" height="1000px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" zoomAndPan="disable">
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
  .p-4 { fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.16); }
  .p-3 { fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.12); }
  .p-2 { fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.08); }
  .p-1 { fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.04); }
  .p0 { fill: none; }
  .p1 { fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.025); }
  .p2 { fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.05); }
  .p3 { fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.075); }
  .p4 { fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.1); }
    ]]></style>
 <polygon class="p-4" points="-1125,0 -375,1000 125,1000 -875,0" />
 <polygon class="p-3" points="-875,0 125,1000 375,1000 -625,0" />
 <polygon class="p-2" points="-625,0 375,1000 625,1000 -375,0" />
 <polygon class="p-1" points="-375,0 625,1000 875,1000 -125,0" />
 <polygon class="p0" points="-125,0 875,1000 1125,1000 125,0" />
 <polygon class="p1" points="125,0 1125,1000 1375,1000 375,0" />
 <polygon class="p2" points="375,0 1375,1000 1625,1000 625,0" />
 <polygon class="p3" points="625,0 1625,1000 1875,1000 875,0" />
 <polygon class="p4" points="875,0 1875,1000 2125,1000 1125,0" />
</svg>
```

**UPDATED SVG FILE:**

```css
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1000px" height="1000px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" zoomAndPan="disable">
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
  .p-4 { fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.16); }
  .p-3 { fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.12); }
  .p-2 { fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.08); }
  .p-1 { fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.04); }
  .p0 { fill: none; }
  .p1 { fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.025); }
  .p2 { fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.05); }
  .p3 { fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.075); }
  .p4 { fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.1); }
    ]]></style>
 <polygon class="p-4" points="-1125,0 -375,1000 125,1000 -875,0" />
 <polygon class="p-3" points="-875,0 125,1000 375,1000 -625,0" />
 <polygon class="p-2" points="-625,0 375,1000 625,1000 -375,0" />
 <polygon class="p-1" points="-375,0 625,1000 875,1000 -125,0" />
 <polygon class="p0" points="-125,0 875,1000 1125,1000 125,0" />
 <polygon class="p1" points="125,0 1125,1000 1375,1000 375,0" />
 <polygon class="p2" points="375,0 1375,1000 1625,1000 625,0" />
 <polygon class="p3" points="625,0 1625,1000 1875,1000 875,0" />
 <polygon class="p4" points="875,0 1875,1000 2125,1000 1125,0" />
 <image x="20" y="20" width="477" height="640"
     xlink:href=../../../images/my_image.png"" />
</svg>
```

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/image-element.html

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks man, that was actually exactly what I was after. Pretty useful stuff there. I managed to add my image to the SVG file, but what I fail to understand is how I can lock it with the polygons so that it stays the same size when zooming in or out (my web design is responsive so it's important that the image I added to the SVG stays the same size when zooming in or out since the rest of the SVG does so too).

Comment: It should be keeping its position relative to the other elements in the SVG. Please post your updated SVG so we can see what you have done.

Comment: Added to the main post @PaulLeBeau

Answer (score 0):

You can add a clipPath as the polygon where you want the image to show.

e.g for p2:

```
<defs>
<clipPath id="polygon_p2_mask">
<polygon points="375,0 1375,1000 1625,1000 625,0" />
</clipPath>
</defs>
```

Then at your image:

```
<image clip-path="url(#polygon_p2_mask)" .... />
```

Note: You then do not require polygon class="p2"

Answer (score 0):

You can turn one of your polygons into a clipping path to restrict your image to one "slice".

Note some of the other things I've done to the example below:

1. I have removed the `width` and `height` attributes from the `<svg>` tag. This will now mean that the SVG scales to fit the page (or its parent). Instead of being fixed at size 1000x1000.  See below.
2. I have set the image to have `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"`. This is equivalent to `backrgound-size: cover` on HTML elements. It ensures the image fills the entirety of the 1000x1000 image size without any gaps around the edges.

Finally I want to point out that your first four slices are white with varying levels of opacity. Was that intended? On a white background they are not going to show up (white on white).

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" zoomAndPan="disable">
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
  .p-4 { fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.16); }
  .p-3 { fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.12); }
  .p-2 { fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.08); }
  .p-1 { fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.04); }
  .p0 { fill: none; }
  .p1 { fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.025); }
  .p2 { fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.05); }
  .p3 { fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.075); }
  .p4 { fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.1); }
    ]]></style>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="p1-clip">
      <polygon points="125,0 1125,1000 1375,1000 375,0"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
 <polygon class="p-4" points="-1125,0 -375,1000 125,1000 -875,0" />
 <polygon class="p-3" points="-875,0 125,1000 375,1000 -625,0" />
 <polygon class="p-2" points="-625,0 375,1000 625,1000 -375,0" />
 <polygon class="p-1" points="-375,0 625,1000 875,1000 -125,0" />
 <polygon class="p0" points="-125,0 875,1000 1125,1000 125,0" />
 <!-- <polygon class="p1" points="125,0 1125,1000 1375,1000 375,0" /> -->
 <polygon class="p2" points="375,0 1375,1000 1625,1000 625,0" />
 <polygon class="p3" points="625,0 1625,1000 1875,1000 875,0" />
 <polygon class="p4" points="875,0 1875,1000 2125,1000 1125,0" />
 <image x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="1000"
           preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
           xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/640/477"
           clip-path="url(#p1-clip)" />
</svg>
```